# Delete the same PHP file in all directories/subfolders at once

Tags: javascript, php

How can I delete a single file in all folders/subfolders using PHP or JS?

Example: Delete "**sample.php**" file in all folders

```
Main/sample.php
Main/css/sample.php
Main/js/sample.php
Main/css/bs/sample.php
and so on...
```

There are more than 300 folders/subfolders in my web server directory.

Thanks.

Comment: Look into the [recursive directory iterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

Comment: Unless you're using NodeJS on the server then you can't use Javascript for this. But if you're using PHP on the server, then you are unlikely to be using Node as well. Browser-based Javascript can't access your filesystem.

Comment: I'd suggest just SSH-ing onto the server and using a shell command if you can; probably something like `find . -type f -name 'sample.php' -exec rm {} +`

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Mere “how can I do that” questions do not really belong here in the first place. You are supposed to go and do your own research, read up on stuff, and try something. _After_ you done that and present your results, we have something to discuss.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this in php:

```
delete('Main', 'sample.php');
function delete($dir, $file) {
    foreach (scandir($dir) as $fileOrDir) {
        if ($fileOrDir == '.' || $fileOrDir == '..') continue;
        if ($fileOrDir == $file) unlink($dir.'/'.$fileOrDir);
        if (is_dir($dir.'/'.$fileOrDir)) delete($dir.'/'.$fileOrDir, $file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP built-in `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`:

```
// Construct the iterator
$iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("Main");

// Loop through files
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator) as $file) {
    if ($file->getFilename() === 'sample.php') {
        unlink($file->getPathname());
    }
}
```